# Using REGEXP to extract specific text between slashes from URL

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

We started using Google Data Studio to visualize our data, and we need RegEx to help us extract a specific piece of text from the URL list from our system.

URL example:

```
/town/articletype/46646-this-is-an-example-article
```

What we need from the URL by using RegEx:

- `/town/` (without slashes, and eventually capitalized the first letter, if possible)
- `/articletype/` (also without slashes)
- `/46646-` (without / and - && this is the article ID we also need)
- `-this-is-an-example-article` (without "-" and capitalized first letter)

We tried numerous RegEx, and we managed to extract `/town/` from the URL by using the following Calculated Field:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page , '/(.*?)(/)')
```

Comment: If we can consider the URL will always follow that format, this expression will give you 4 groups containing each part of your URL: `^\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)-(\S+)$`. Now, about removing the `-` and capitalizing, I suggest you do that using something else other than regular expressions.

Comment: Gerep, thanks, this is great! I don't think we can use groups for our needs, our best way is to use separate expressions for each part of the URL. I managed to make it work for the town, article ID and an article name, but can't make it work for article type. I'm not sure what I am missing here. Just to clarify: TOWN: ^\/([a-z]+)\/ --- ARTICLE ID: ([0-9]+) --- ARTICLE NAME: -(\S+)$.

Comment: Because town and article type has the same pattern, the best thing is to match them at once as suggested by @Gerep. Or you can use the town pattern with g flag and get the second matched item if you must do them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below do the trick:

**1) Town**

```
CONCAT(UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page , "^/(\\w{1})")), LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page , "^/\\w{1}([^/]*)")))
```

**2) articletype**

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page , "^/\\w+/([^/]*)")
```

**3) 46646**

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page , "^/\\w+/\\w+/([^-]*)")
```

**4) This is an example article**

```
CONCAT(UPPER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page , "/\\w+/\\w+/\\d+-(\\w{1}).*$")), LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page , "/\\w+/\\w+/\\d+-\\w{1}(.*)$"), "-", " ")))
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3a194298-7a9b-4850-a43f-085234f55ce8) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]